# Sending huge array through socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to send a char array of 100.000.000 bytes (maybe more) from a server to a client through a TCP socket in C.

I am doing this like that:

```
char *array;  // global array malloc'd (SIZE)

//#######################
//    server code
//#######################
int i;
int SIZE = 100000000

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i = i + 4){  
    write(id, &array[i], 4);   // write 4 bytes every time
}

//#######################
//    client code
//#######################
int i;
int SIZE = 100.000.000
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i = i + 4)
    read(id, array + i, 4);    // read 4 bytes
```

Problems:

1) When I try to send more bytes something goes wrong with the transfer. For example if I change 4 to 100, it says "broken pipe". Why does that happen?

2) I know this is not a "safe" way for reading/writing since I am not checking read() and write() return values. How can I do that?

3) Do I have to use htonl() and ntohl() functions?

Comment: Normally, this kind of problem is solved with block sizes of 2^x (something around 0x1000) or according to tcp/ip frames (like 1460). But your code looks incomplete and inconsistent. Why do you use the different syntaxes `&array[i]` and `array + i` which are equal in how they work? And did you correctly `malloc` the array before receiving?

Comment: Use `const unsigned long` for SIZE or better `const size_t` (although not propable, int may be only 16 bits, size_t also, but then you are busted anyway, as size_t is guaranteed to hold the max. allowed index of an array). Or, better, use a #define which will generate a proper constant. If `SIZE` is intended to be change, you should not use uppercase, as this is used normally for #defines (macros) and enum-constants. Note there is a funcamental difference for `const` in C and `C++` (if you are more familar with the latter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>          
 #include <sys/socket.h>   

 //in @param
 //@param fd the socket file descriptor
 //@param array an array of data source to write to send to the connected client 
 //@param SIZE the size of data source to send to the client
 //@param sz_emit the size of data to send in one loop step
 //out @param
 //total length of data emited to the client

 int write_to_client(int fd, char* array, int SIZE, int sz_emit)
 {
   //#######################
   //    server code
   //#######################
   int i=0, sz=0;
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i += sz_emit )
   {  
       while(sz_emit-sz)
       { 
         sz+=write(id, array+i+sz, sz_emit-sz);
       }
       sz = 0;
   }
   return i;
 }

//#######################
//    client code
//#######################
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          
#include <sys/socket.h>

//in @param
//@param fd is the file descriptor of the socket to read from
//@param SIZE the size of datas you want to read from the socket
//@param sz_received the size of byte to read in one loop step
//@param length, the length of data received
//@param read_err if 0 no error if -1 an error occurs use errno from #include <errno.h> to know more about that error 
//out @param
//a pointer to an array of size SIZE containing the data readed
char* receive_from_server(int fd, int SIZE, int sz_received, int* length, int* read_err)
{
  *read_err = 0;
  int i = 0, sz = 0, rt = 0, count=0;
  char *array = (char *)malloc(SIZE);
  memset(array, 0, SIZE);  
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i += sz_received)
    {
      while(sz_received-sz)
      { 
        rt = read(id, array + i + sz, sz_received-sz);
        if(rt==-1)
        {
          *read_err=rt;
          printf("an error occurs\n");
          goto l;
        }
        if(!rt)goto l;
        sz+=rt;
        count += sz;   
      }
      sz = 0;
    }
  l: *length = count;
  return array;
}
```

usage:

```
//server side
int SIZE = 100000000;
char array_to_send[SIZE]={'r'};
int sz_data_emited = write_to_client(sock, array_to_send, SIZE, 4);
printf("how many byte data emited:%d\n", sz_data_emited);

//client side
int SIZE = 100000000, length = 0, read_err=0;
char*array_received = NULL;
array_received = receive_from_server(sock, SIZE, 4, &length, &read_err);
if(!read_err)printf("get some datas\n");
// free array_received when finished...free(array_received)
```

some notes:

you need to pay attention on endianess when you want to transfert a multi-byte entity for example a short, int, long, utf-16 etc but if your datas are utf-8 or ascii text you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Edit your post if you want, it has some minor mistakes ;)

Comment: You're ignoring the value returns by `read()`, and assuming it is positive. There are two other possibilities that you must test for.

Comment: What is the recommanded sz_emit value? for sending png image full hd?

Answer (score 0):

I think that *`Narcisse Doudieu Siewe`* answer has some **errors**. I suppose `it fails when SIZE isn't multiplicity of sz_emit`. 
Example there is 20 bytes that we sent in 8 bytes chunkes than the last data chunk (or packet) will be 4 byte long. Than if we try to send the last 8 bytes chunk and there is only 4 bytes left while loop will be infinite as while(8 - 4), and it never reaches sz = 8, as the next send will just increment by 0. So I write modification like this (not tested, I will test soon and write also second method taking into account this boundary condition).

```
/**
 * @param sock_fd - the file descriptor of the socket to write (send) data to
 * @param packetLength - the size of data to send in one packet
 * @param data - binary data to send (unsigned char array)
 * @param dataLength - the size of all binary data to send
 * @return  - status code SUCCESS or FAILURE
 */
result_t send_binary(const sock_fd_t sock_fd, const size_t packetLength, const unsigned char *data, const size_t dataLength) {

    ssize_t leftPacketLength = 0;
    ssize_t offset = 0;
    ssize_t sentPacketLength = 0;

    // send each packet of data in the loop
    for(int leftDataLength=dataLength; leftDataLength>0; leftDataLength -= packetLength) {

        leftPacketLength = (leftDataLength > packetLength) ? packetLength : leftDataLength;
        while(leftPacketLength > 0) {
            sentPacketLength = send(sock_fd, data + offset, leftPacketLength, 0);
            if(sentPacketLength < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error while sending data to the socket.\n", __func__);
                perror(errno);
                return FAILURE;
            }
            offset += sentPacketLength;
            leftPacketLength -= sentPacketLength;
        }
    }

    if(offset != dataLength)
        return FAILURE;

    return SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * @param sock_fd - the file descriptor of the socket to read (recieve) data from
 * @param packetLength - the size of data to recieve in one packet
 * @param data - binary data received (unsigned char array) - previously allocated
 * @param dataLength - the size of all binary data received - previously defined
 * @return - status code SUCCESS or FAILURE
 */
result_t recv_binary(const sock_fd_t sock_fd, const size_t packetLength, unsigned char *data, const size_t dataLength) {

    ssize_t leftPacketLength = 0;
    ssize_t offset = 0;
    ssize_t recvedPacketLength = 0;


    for(int leftDataLength=dataLength; leftDataLength > 0; leftDataLength -= packetLength) {

        leftPacketLength = (leftDataLength > packetLength) ? packetLength : leftDataLength;
        while(leftPacketLength > 0) {
            recvedPacketLength = recv(sock_fd, data + offset, leftPacketLength, 0);
            if(recvedPacketLength < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error while receiving data from the socket.\n", __func__);
                perror(errno);
                return FAILURE;
            }
            offset += recvedPacketLength;
            leftPacketLength -= recvedPacketLength;
        }
    }

    if(offset != dataLength)
        return FAILURE;

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

There is also need to send size of binary data send/recv via socket before transfering actual binary data. It's needed to know how many bytes we need to read.